# Spring Data Rest for MongoDB: How to find by sub-document id

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using Spring Data Rest for MongoDB. I'm trying to find documents by sub-document id.

```
class A {
  @Id
  private String id;
  private String name;
}

class B {
  @Id
  private String id;
  private String name;
  private A a;
}

@RepositoryRestResource()
public interface BRepository extends MongoRepository<B, String> {
  List<B> findByA_Id(@Param("aId") String aId);
  List<B> findByA_Name(@Param("aName") String aName);
}
```

The issue is the `findByA_Id` method always returns back an empty list. The function `findByA_Name` works fine though.

Comment: Why do add those @Param annotations?